# Implements parcelable in an object with nested non-primitive elements

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have an object in the form

```
public class Car implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String name;
    String description;
    String brand;
    int speed;
    int brake;
    int asset;
    ArrayList<Uri> images;

    public Car(String name, String description, String brand, int speed,
            int brake, int asset, ArrayList<Uri> images) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.brake = brake;
        this.asset = asset;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getBrake() {
        return brake;
    }

    public void setBrake(int brake) {
        this.brake = brake;
    }

    public int getAsset() {
        return asset;
    }

    public void setAsset(int asset) {
        this.asset = asset;
    }

    public ArrayList<Uri> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(ArrayList<Uri> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + asset;
        result = prime * result + brake;
        result = prime * result + ((brand == null) ? 0 : brand.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((images == null) ? 0 : images.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + speed;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [name=" + name + ", description=" + description
                + ", brand=" + brand + ", speed=" + speed + ", brake=" + brake
                + ", asset=" + asset + ", images=" + images + "]";
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

But I haven't understand how to implements

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and

```
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

that Eclipse have required after the adding of `implements Parcelable` to the class

on the Android site the sample show also a method

```
  public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }
```

What is the right way to make my whole class (and all the nested objects as ArrayList) *"Parcelable"*?

following the sample I'm arrived to the constructor

```
public Car(Parcel in) {
   name= in.readString();
 description= in.readString();
speed=in.readInt();
...

images=in.readArrayList(??????????????????);
}
```

what is the Class loader to pass in `readArrayList(..)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `writeToParcel` method you should do:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(brand); //To write String
}
```

The argument `dest` in the `writeToParcel` method has a lot of other methods to write other object or raw types.
To put other objects that do not have specific methods in the `dest` object, you should use the methods `writeParcelable` if the object you are trying to write implements `Parcelable` or `writeSerializable` if the object you are trying to write implements `Serializable`.

After, when you'll recover your Parceable object, you should use:

```
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    brand = in.readString(); //To read String
}
```

You have to read the values from the in object in the same order you wrote them.

The piece of code:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Car> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Car>() {
         public Car createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new Car(in);
         }
}
```

Is necessary to call the `readFromParcel` method. You should add in your class a constructor to be called from the piece of code above.
The constructor should look like:

```
public Car(Parcel in) {
   readFromParcel(in);
}
```

About the method `describeContents`, there is a good answer on Stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076946/parcelable-where-when-is-describecontents-used).

Summarizing, I've never seen any case in which this method was used. The method is used if you want to release resources after the parsing of the Parcel, but I didin't found any good material on the internet explaining it. Chances are that you'll keep it returning 0.
You can found Android documentation for it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html#describeContents%28%29).

Comment: I'm following the sample but in public Car(Parcel in) {...} now I'm arrived at images=in.readArrayList(Class loader) and I have no idea of what I should pass. For the primitives is simply name=in.readString() speed=in.readInt()etc.

Comment: You should use `writeSerializable` to write, and `readSerializable` to read. You can see all the methods [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)