# use of Parcelable interface..?

Tags: android

explain what meaning of Parcelable.creator?

```
 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };
```

Comment: always try to Google it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parcelable objects allow you to serialise and deserialise on activity or fragment stop / start and it is **Faster** than Java serialisable.

The static CREATOR class creates your object from a Parcel via the createFromParcel method that takes in a parcel and passes it to a constructor in your class that does the grunt work.

The newArray method allows an array of your objects to be parcelled. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076946/parcelable-where-when-is-describecontents-used/4914799#4914799)

And here is a good example of it [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/1364896)

Answer (score 1):

`Parcelable.Creator` creates instances of your `MyParcelable` from a `Parcel` object. For example the typic `Parcelable` should look like this :

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

For more information you should check the official documentation :

- [Parcelable.Creator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html)
- [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)